# What would a gondola carried by a giant bird look like?

Tags: avian, shipbuilding, transport

In the world I'm designing there is an island with a kingdom there, people in that kingdom have learned to tame giant birds and use them for transport. One such means of transport is a gondola with a pole on top for the bird to grab and carry through the air. However, the gondola cannot be too big if it is not going to be too heavy for the bird to carry and if it is too small it can be fragile. The gondola has to be light enough for the bird to carry, but also tough enough to withstand turbulence during flight and not break under the weight of the people inside. **What would the design of such a gondola look like?**

The giant birds are the same size as the Great Eagles from The Lord of the Rings. The materials have to be easily acquired for a civilization that has not experienced an industrial revolution. If you can, try to say how many people you think would fit in the gondola.

Comment: Why not just make normal seats but with a couple of belts to fasten people well. Connect that with ropes to a metal bar or wooden beam, then have the birds carry it? You saved a lot of weight and materials and troubles for the birds. The more weight the bird has to carry, the bigger and stronger it has to become. It's just easier to have boats at both points of travel than trying to have super birds. That is if you need the gondolas for water navigation in the first place.
Exact size and ability of your birds? Google shows that eagles from ME can vary. Biggest had a wingspan of 55 m.

Comment: This link says that the eagles in the films were 6 meters tall and 23 meters wide. And I don't know what you mean by "eagles from ME? What is ME? I'm not a super fan of lord of the rings to know, everything I know I researched out of curiosity. https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Eagles

Comment: Boats would take longer, if I wanted more travel time I wouldn't even have giant birds to serve as transport.

Comment: If your idea of ​​seat belts connected to ropes is such a good idea, then don't post a comment, post a reply. As long as it has walls so it doesn't blow the air in the crew's faces during the trip.

Comment: ME=Middle-earth. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_(Middle-earth) says: In The Silmarillion, Thorondor is said to have been the greatest of them and of all birds, with a wingspan of 30 fathoms (55 m; 180 ft).
I asked in a comment cuz I was not sure if you considered or not, I don't care much about rep. If that helps or makes you rule them out with an in universe example then good.
I know it's way more practical than adding hundreds of kilos to the poor thing. Worrying about structural integrity or air resistance...etc. I guess frames challenges exist but again I just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 5):

Have you ever heard of the story that babies are brought by the stork?

[image]

I think that is the most lightweight design one can have: a sort of hammock, where the passenger would stay while the whole thing is carried by the giant bird. Maybe with some cushions/stuffing to give a bit more comfort and insulation.

Carrying it with the talons instead that with the beak won't change the design that much.